# Apache POI 3.9 can not get HSSFPalette

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, palette

I am using apache poi 3.9. I need to have a custom color in my excel. 
On the apache documentation and some other suggestions there is a code:

`Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();`
`HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();`

but Workbook does not have method getCustomPalette().
Please help me to find out how can I have a custom color on the cells

Thanks

Comment: Yes it does: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getCustomPalette().  If that doesn't work you'll have to give more details.

Comment: I get compile error because there is no such method in the HSSFWorkBook.

Comment: I have poi-ooxml and poi dependencies in my pom.xml
do I need to add another library?

Comment: poi-ooxml dependency is enough but the check the version which you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found it. should be:

`HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();`

instead of:

`Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();`